# How to set CSS rules for input, except one type

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have CSS rules for `input` as

```
input {
background:#FFFFFF
}
input:hover {
background:#BBBBBB
}
```

I want to apply this style to all `input` elements, except one (e.g., `type="submit"`).

How can I exclude one input type from a CSS style?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the [`:not()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#negation) pseudo-class and an attribute selector, e.g.

```
input:not([type=submit]) {
    background: slategray;
}
```

Keep in mind there is no support for IE 8 and below.

http://jsfiddle.net/qpxYb/1/

Comment: I knew about `not`, but how can I use it with `:hover`?

Comment: Just attach it at the end, e.g. `input:not([type=submit]):hover {}`

Comment: add :hover behind the selector

Answer (score 5):

You may use the `:not()` selector.

```
input:not([type='submit']):hover {
/* rules here */
}
```

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:not

Answer (score 2):

You can just overwrite the general input field style with a new style for submit input fields. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/dpYRX/2/

```
input {
background:#FFFFFF
}
input:hover {
background:#BBBBBB
}

input[type="submit"] {
    background: #ff0000;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #cdcdcd;
}
```